# Unable to use useRef in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, chart.js

I am unable to use the ref prop for the line chart and pie chart that I am working on.

I have tried to set different types for useRef and I am always getting the error

`Type 'RefObject<Chart<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, (number | [number, number] | Point | BubbleDataPoint | null)[], unknown>>' is not assignable to type 'ForwardedRef<ChartJSOrUndefined<"pie", (number | [number, number] | Point | BubbleDataPoint | null)[], unknown>> | undefined'.`

The following is the source code:-

```
import { useState,useRef, MouseEvent} from 'react';
declare const Data: { mark: unknown }[];
import {Chart, Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
import { getElementAtEvent } from 'react-chartjs-2/dist/utils';


ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
)


export default function App() {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    labels: Data.map(item => item.mark), 
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Marks',
        data: Data.map(item => item.mark),
        backgroundColor: '#2a71d0',
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    ]
  });
  const chartRef = useRef<ChartJS>(null);

  const onclick = (e:MouseEvent<HTMLCanvasElement>) => {
    if (chartRef.current) {
      console.log(getElementAtEvent(chartRef.current,e))
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className='PerformanceChart'>
      <Line ref={chartRef} data={chartData} onClick={onclick}   />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are `<Line />` and `<canvas />` the same?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the type of your useRef to `ChartJS`:

```
const chartRef = useRef<ChartJS>(null)
```

Comment: I did that but i still cant use the getElementAtEvent() and I am getting the same error

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74930440/unable-to-use-useref-in-typescript#comment132232382_74930528) @magicrap This answer is correct. Also, see lines 44–49 in this TS Playground: https://tsplay.dev/wgAo9m

Comment: @Farnam This doesn't seem to be working anymore

Answer (score 0):

Farnam's solution no longer seems to work (see the error in https://tsplay.dev/wgAo9m) and I couldn't find this `ChartJSOrUndefined` type.

For me it worked to just add an additional `undefined` option to the `useRef` type:

```
useRef<ChartJS<"bar"> | undefined>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` prop of `<Line>` expects a type of `ChartJS<"line">`, make sure your `useRef` is declared as such:

```
// No need to initialize to `null`; React's TS types will infer the resulting
// type to be `ChartJS<"line"> | undefined`.
const chartRef = useRef<ChartJS<"line">>();
```